# jQuery DatePicker Year Problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is my `datepicker` setup:

```
 $('#game_datepicker').datepicker({
    yearRange: "-3:+0",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'M/dd/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, object) {
        console.log(dateText);
      object.input.parent().find('label').hide();
    }
  });
```

So the dropdown for year is 2010-2013, but when I actually choose a date, the year that is set is 1990. When I inspect the dates in the calendar grid the `data-year` is set to 1990. Anyone else run into this issue? I can't seem to get it working properly

Comment: it is working like it should here. see: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qEb7c/)

Comment: Working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/sCZHW/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the other interaction... when a user selects a date, the date is placed inside of the input that is attached to the datepicker...

Comment: @dennismonsewicz which input are you talking? If necessary show some of your html or some printscreen. See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qEb7c/1/) input text is correctly inserted in that input